# Java JAI access error in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, image-processing, java, jai

I'm having this error while importing JAI(Java Advanced Imaging) library.

```
PlanarImage image = JAI.create("fileload", "image12.tiff");
```

It says the following error:

```
Access restriction: The type PlanarImage is not accessible due to restriction on required library C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\lib\ext\jai_core.jar
```

I do not understand the reason. My JRE version is 6.

Please help, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is given [here](http://www.digizol.com/2008/09/eclipse-access-restriction-on-library.html).

In short it says you can ignore this type of error by changing the settings under

*(Project) Properties -> Java Compiler -> Errors/Warnings*

(Did you Google the error message? The above page was the first hit.)

Comment: hi aioobe, thanks for response. Yes I did google it a bit. But the link you have given doesn't seem to work in my pc. I mean, I couldn't reach the URL(reason unknown). that's why I've posted it here. Thanks anyway.